# Sprite UV returning wrong values in script in newer Unity versions

Tags: unity, sprites

I'm recreating in Unity 2019.4 an old project I have done few years ago in Unity 5.4.0. This project consists of a tiled map editor using unity editor scripts which reads baked data files containing all information needed for each tile (like height, texture id and texture rotation) and creates the tiled mesh on the fly for a given map to be edited in unity.

I have a single sprite (mode: multiple) containing all tiles textures that I read when creating the terrain mesh to set the correct UV for each vertex of the mesh depending on the texture id of a given tile.

In my old project using Unity 5.4.0 I can just call a tile sub sprite `uv` property to set in the mesh uv and it works just fine. The problem is that in Unity 2019.4 the `uv` property of the exact same asset (the big sprite with multiple sub sprites) returns weird values.

I compared the output of the `uv` property used in each tile on both projects and the values are slightly different. The difference is just the order how the elements are ordered in the `uv` array.

Lastly I noticed the sprite is showing additional options in Unity 2019. I have played with the options in Unity 2019 but couldn't notice any difference in the problem. I'll link the images showing the options in both Unity 5 and Unity 2019 bellow (respectively):

[image: Unity 5.4.0]

[image: Unity 2019.4]

Does anyone have **any** idea or suggestion to understand why this is happening? I tried to search for this topic but couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

EDIT: the multiple sprite is being generated and imported with the tool TexturePacker.

Comment: As an alternative to using Texture Packer and making your import more complicated, you can import the sprites as separate images and combine them into one texture using a Sprite Atlas: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteAtlas.html

Comment: @Kevin but why do I get different `uv`s depending on the unity version I'm using? This doesn't seem to have any direct relation with the Texture Packer as I'm not calling or relying directly on any TexturePacker code. The tool just generates a multiple sprite for me.

Comment: I haven't used Unity 5 in a long time and can't comment on the `uv` property, though it sounds like the Unity team reorganized the data in a way that would be considered a breaking change. It's not surprising to experience a breaking change when upgrading from 5.4 to 2019.4. In fact, you're lucky if that's the only thing that broke when upgrading. It would probably make your question clearer if you shared a few lines of code and what the output looks like in each of the versions.

Comment: @Kevin I just managed to create a quick fix for the problem. It was the `Mesh Type` of the sprite. Both options in Unity 2019  ("Tight" and "Full Rect") will change how the `uv` elements are ordered in the array. Unity 5.4 doesn't even have such an option. Fortunately I could observe a pattern on how the "Tight" option sort the array so I just reordered in the order the old code expected and the whole thing worked like a charm.

Comment: Great! Please post your solution as the answer to help anyone else who has a similar problem in the future.

Comment: I'll do as far as I understand what is going on under the hood.